# Login loop, Linux mint cinnamon 19

Tags: linux-mint, login

I'm using a dual booting laptop for the last two month ish (azus zenbook with mint and win10), and its not the first time I'm facing this problem.

Until now, every time I use the command (from ctrl+alt+f1 terminal..)

$ sudo chown -Rc $USER : $USER $HOME

alt + f7, and life back to normal.

But this time its not doing the same trick :/

After

{ chown: cannot access 'hagai' : no such file or directory }

There is no

{ chown: switch root from 'root' to 'hagai' }

Or something like it that use to be, and the login loop crash still happening...

I guess that this specific time what triggered the loop was installation of XAMPP and bit messing with

{ su root }

For running that env.

Another thing that may be relevant that every time I'm trying to install apt apps (like mdm that was suggested in one of the answers out in the web), I'm getting

{ you don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/ }

Although I have 700mb free there,

Also 
{sudo apt-get clean/autoclean/autoremove }

Not doing nothing,

Don't know if its relevant...

Hope someone there will come for rescue!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the **partition `/` fully filled**. Just before leaving session had appeared a warning of full memory, and when I tried to return to the session I could not. I tried everything, but browsing the computer using Live USB with Linux Mint, I noticed that the `/` partition was totally full. I freed up space by moving some files from `/var/lib/` to `/home/`, and the problem disappeared. My SSD is all partitioned, and for partition `/` I had reserved 65 GB of memory. I had gone through this problem before, and had to reinstall the operating system, but it was because of an accident, where I deleted all the contents of the `/tmp/` folder.